Are samples generated by a computer from a Gaussian distribution biased?
Recently I have been reading some blogs about Gaussian processes, where they use the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ to generate a sequence of points $(x_1, x_2 ...x_n)$, and these points together look like a real function.
However, I don't quite understand why this phenomenon occurs. I mean, everything is probabilistic, right? So there could be some noise samples - a sequence of $(x_1, x_2 ...x_n)$ that when put together don't resemble any smooth function, but it seems like this doesn't happen?
Furthermore, regarding how computers generate samples from an gaussian $\mathcal{N}$ distribution, I have heard about the reparameterization trick : $x\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma) \rightarrow x = \mu + \sigma \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. However, we can only be sure that $x$ will follow the $\mathcal{N}$ distribution, not every sample from the $\mathcal{N}$ distribution will be generated correctly using this trick, right? I mean, this relationship is one-way, so are we biased towards certain samples?

There is a change that happens when we go from talking about the whole function being drawn from a GP versus drawing a normal distribution at a set of points. Regarding "So there could be some noise samples - a sequence of (x1,x2...xn) that when put together don't resemble any smooth function." What would it mean for a finite set of points not to resemble a smooth function? The individual points are going to be a finite distance apart; we could still draw a smooth function through any finite set of points.
But what the smoothness[1] of the GP gives us is the following, which we need only two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ to illustrate. If we make $x_1$ go arbitrarily close to $x_2$, then the output of the GP at the two points $y(x_1),y(x_2)$ have to agree: the covariance matrix becomes singular! When the points are not identical but only very close, then we have a very nearly degenerate covariance matrix. In theory, because they have a nonsingular joint Gaussian, it is indeed possible that they have wildly different values; this just happens with vanishingly small probability such that it would basically never be observed in practice even with infinite precision.
Indeed, if you give me any closeness $\epsilon_y$ that $y(x_1)$ and $y(x_2)$ have to be together (i.e. $|y(x_1)-y(x_2)|<\epsilon_y$) and some probability $\rho$ that this closeness has to be satisfied with, I can give you some $\epsilon_x$ such that this will be achieved whenever $|x_1-x_2|<\epsilon_x$.
I don't understand what you're getting at with your final paragraph. It is indeed the case that if $\mathbf{y}\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $\Sigma=\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^\top$, then we can simulate $\mathbf{y}$ using iid normal variables $\mathbf{z}$ as $\mathbf{L}\mathbf{z}+\mu$; this transformation is invertible for nondegenerate covariance (so not ``one way") and is not biased.
[1] I am assuming here an infinitely smooth GP, such as that induced by an RBF/Gaussian/SE kernel.
